# Draw multiple objects with textures

Tags: opengl-es-2.0

I want to draw cubes using textures.

```
void OperateWithMainMatrix(ESContext* esContext, GLfloat offsetX, GLfloat offsetY, GLfloat offsetZ) {

UserData *userData = (UserData*) esContext->userData;
ESMatrix modelview;
ESMatrix perspective;
    //Manipulation with matrix 
    ...
    glVertexAttribPointer(userData->positionLoc, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, cubeFaces);
    //in cubeFaces coordinates verticles cube
    glVertexAttribPointer(userData->normalLoc, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, cubeFaces);
    //for normals (use in fragment shaider for textures)

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(userData->positionLoc);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(userData->normalLoc);

    // Load the MVP matrix
    glUniformMatrix4fv(userData->mvpLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, 
                       (GLfloat*)&userData->mvpMatrix.m[0][0]);

    //Bind base map
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, userData->baseMapTexId);

    //Set the base map sampler to texture unit to 0
    glUniform1i(userData->baseMapLoc, 0);

   // Draw the cube
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
   }
```

(coordinates transformation is in OperateWithMainMatrix() )
Then Draw() function is called:

```
void Draw(ESContext *esContext)
{
   UserData *userData = esContext->userData;
   // Set the viewport
   glViewport(0, 0, esContext->width, esContext->height);

   // Clear the color buffer
   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

   // Use the program object
   glUseProgram(userData->programObject);

  OperateWithMainMatrix(esContext, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

  eglSwapBuffers(esContext->eglDisplay, esContext->eglSurface);
}
```

This work fine, but if I try to draw multiple cubes (next code for example):

```
void Draw(ESContext *esContext)
{ ...

    // Use the program object
    glUseProgram(userData->programObject);

    OperateWithMainMatrix(esContext, 2.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    OperateWithMainMatrix(esContext, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    OperateWithMainMatrix(esContext, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    OperateWithMainMatrix(esContext, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    OperateWithMainMatrix(esContext, -2.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    eglSwapBuffers(esContext->eglDisplay, esContext->eglSurface);
}
```

A side faces overlapes frontal face. This process is illustrated on image:
[image]

Alternate picture (with colours and clean image):
[image]

The side face of the right cube overlaps frontal face of the center cube.
How can i remove this effect and display miltiple cubes without it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this you need to utilize what's known as the **depth buffer**. This is what's responsible for making sure that surfaces don't get drawn overtop of surfaces that are nearer (like the side of a cube showing over the front of a cube).

Luckily it's not much work involved to do so:

1. Enable depth testing at initialization with `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)`
2. Clear depth buffer on each frame by adding it's bit to the glClear call:
       `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)`

After this you should no longer see your surfaces popping on top of nearer surfaces.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I'm afraid, that it's don't fix problem..
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST) is active in my code, and adding to function draw() glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT) didn't bring the desired result.
Because this effect is observed inside one frame: when i call function OperateWithMainMatrix()  many times.

Comment: @Simplex - what does glGet(GL_DEPTH_BITS) return? How is your projection matrix defined?

Comment: glGet(GL_DEPTH_BITS) return 0
Matrix defined in OperateWithMainMatrix():

 esMatrixLoadIdentity(&perspective);
 esPerspective(&perspective, 60.0f, aspect, 1.0f, 20.0f);
 esMatrixLoadIdentity(&modelview);
 esTranslate(&modelview, offsetX, offsetY, offsetZ);
 
 esTranslate(&perspective, distanceX, 0.0, distance);
 esRotate(&perspective,  userData->angle, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
 esMatrixMultiply(&userData->mvpMatrix, &modelview, &perspective);

Comment: Ah. If your GL_DEPTH_BITS is zero it means that your context has no depth buffer, and thus the depth test will always pass (meaning it is useless). You have to request a depth buffer when you create an OpenGL context. I'm not familiar with that framework, and I don't know where it's context gets created. Do you see anywhere where it creates the context where you might be able to request a depth buffer? @Simplex

Comment: Yes, in creating context don't set flag ES_WINDOW_DEPTH, after setting him:
esCreateWindow(&esContext, "Test Maze", 1024, 600, ES_WINDOW_RGB | ES_WINDOW_DEPTH);
All's ok. Thanks!